# What can qualify as a terminal illness with respect to assisted suicide?

Tags: medical, health

As an example, HIV used to be considered a terminal disease by doctors. Nowadays, there are treatments which extend life significantly for HIV patients, and doctors consider it to be a manageable disease through treatment rather than terminal.

Does the law have an explicit definition of terminal disease? Or what qualifies a disease to be used as a reason for assisted suicide in relevant jurisdiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The law in Washington, [RCW 70.245](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=70.245&full=true), redined "terminal illness" as

> an incurable and irreversible disease that has been medically
>   confirmed and will, within reasonable medical judgment, produce death
>   within six months.

[California law](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=201520162AB15) and [Hawaii law](https://health.hawaii.gov/opppd/files/2018/11/OCOC-Act2.pdf) say the same thing

In Oregon, under [ORS 127.505](https://www.oregonlegislature.gov/bills_laws/ors/ors127.html), the relevant term is "terminal condition", defines as

> a health condition in which death is imminent irrespective of
>   treatment, and where the application of life-sustaining procedures or
>   the artificial administration of nutrition and hydration serves only
>   to postpone the moment of death of the principal.

The [law of The Netherlands](https://www.worldrtd.net/dutch-law-termination-life-request-and-assisted-suicide-complete-text) is less restrictive, and does not involve "terminal" conditions. The most relevant condition from article 2 is that there must be a finding that "the patient's suffering is unbearable with no prospect of improvement" (plus, there are informed consent and a second opinion standards to be met). The [Canadian law](https://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/en/42-1/bill/C-14/royal-assent) in §241.2 requires that "they have a grievous and irremediable medical condition". That means, specifically, that

> (a) they have a serious and incurable illness, disease or disability;
>
> (b) they are in an advanced state of irreversible decline in
>   capability;
>
> (c) that illness, disease or disability or that state of decline
>   causes them enduring physical or psychological suffering that is
>   intolerable to them and that cannot be relieved under conditions that
>   they consider acceptable; and
>
> (d) their natural death has become reasonably foreseeable, taking into
>   account all of their medical circumstances, without a prognosis
>   necessarily having been made as to the specific length of time that
>   they have remaining.

Simply having been exposed to a virus, or even contracting the disease AIDS, does not qualify under the law. At later points in the progression of the diseases, it could – depending on jurisdiction.